# NodeJS Create function crash

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I NEW to nodejs. I used one routes to do two insertion at the same time to two tables. I am using mongo db as my database.
Here is my code

```
router.post('/register',(req, res)=>{
    const newBook = new books({
        bkName: req.body.bkName,
        numberofCopies: req.body.numberofCopies,
        Author: req.body.Author,
        Edition: req.body.Edition,
        AddingDate: req.body.AddingDate
    });
    const numberofbooks = new bookNumber({
        bkName: req.body.bkName,
        numberofCopies: req.body.numberofCopies
    });
    numberofbooks.save((err,doc)=>{
        if(!err){ res.send(doc); }
        else{ console.log('Number of books adding error:'+JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
    newBook.save((err, doc)=>{
        if(!err){ res.send(doc); }
        else{console.log('Books in book Save:'+JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));}
    });
    
    //console.log(numberofbooks);
});
```

I saw some earlier posts. But I donot found such a problem like this. When I run this route in my postman it will add data to both tables and my node server crashed. So I cannot do other things after a insertion.
This is the error I got in my server.

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>
> ```
> at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
> ```

I cannot understand this I am searching a answer this for last two hours. Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send more then one response to a request. The error will be thrown in `newBook.save()` (or `numberofbooks.save()` - whichever finishes second) since you are trying to send a second response to the same request after you've already sent one in the other `save()`. It's not entirely clear what you really want to send, currently there are two different documents returned.

Comment: Thank you very much I understood about my problem